# How to access a component on storyboard in my code in Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

For instance, a button is created on storyboard by drag and drop. How do I access this button and make some changes to it in my code?
I have <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+clicked it to create an IBOUtlet in `ViewController.h`.

How do I access it in ViewController.m?

Comment: Lets say that your outlet named myButton. So in .m file you can use self.myButton or _myButton to access it.

Comment: @4esterUA thanks a lot. Shall I access it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: You may access it from whatever you want within the .m file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understand your question but I will try to help you.
you can call global variables using the (SELF)
for example: self.(method name) = (function).
an example in my code >> self.categoryText.text = self.category;

Comment: Let's say, I created a button on storyboard. Now how do I change its title using code?

Comment: if I remember well if you put the button you create with (.text = @ "name") it will change the button name!